# hwo add out of stock product cart (woocomerce)

Tags: php, wordpress

hwo add out of stock product cart (woocomerce)

I don't now what I can do?  This code but not working:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_is_purchasable', 'allow_out_of_stock_and_on_backorder_to_cart', 10, 2);

function allow_out_of_stock_and_on_backorder_to_cart($purchasable, $product) {
    // Check if the product is not purchasable and has either "out_of_stock" or "onbackorder" status.
    if (!$purchasable && in_array($product->get_stock_status(), array('out_of_stock', 'onbackorder'))) {
        return true; // Allow the product to be added to the cart.
    }

    if (!$purchasable && $product->is_type('variable')) {
        // For variable products, check if at least one variation is purchasable.
        $variations = $product->get_available_variations();
        foreach ($variations as $variation) {
            if ($variation['is_purchasable']) {
                return true; // Allow the variable product to be added to the cart.
            }
        }
    }

    return $purchasable; // Return the original purchasable status for other products.
}
```